# Can the Hochschild cochain complex be given the structure of a "homotopy BV algebra"?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, hochschild-cohomology

In a 1993 letter, Deligne posed the following (paraphrased from a [paper of Gerstenhaber and Voronov's](http://www.math.umn.edu/~voronov/del.pdf)):

> > **Conjecture (Deligne).** The Hochschild cochain complex $CC^*(A)$ of an associative algebra $A$ has a natural structure of an algebra over a chain operad of the little 2-disks operad $E_2$.

("Chain operad of $E_2$" means any operad in $Ch$ whose homology is isomorphic to the homology of $E_2$, i.e. to the Gerstenhaber operad.)

Various versions of Deligne's conjecture have been proven, e.g. by [Gerstenhaber-Voronov](http://www.math.umn.edu/~voronov/del.pdf), [Tamarkin](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9803025), [Voronov](http://lanl.arxiv.org/abs/math/9908040), [McClure-Smith](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9910126) (see also [1](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0106024), [2](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211368)), and [Kontsevich-Soibelman](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0001151).

Now, in some situations, $HH^*(A)$ can be equipped with a BV operator $\Delta$ compatible with the Gerstenhaber algebra structure, so that it becomes a BV algebra.  For instance, this was proven by [Tradler](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0210150) in the case that $A$ is unital and equipped with a symmetric, invariant, and non-degenerate inner product.  And BV algebras are the same thing as algebras over the framed little 2-disks operad $\tilde E_2$. So...

> > **Question:** With suitable hypotheses on $A$, can $CC^*(A)$ be given the structure of an algebra over a chain operad of $\tilde E_2$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is the "cyclic Deligne conjecture", which also has several proofs by now. I believe the first one was Kaufmann's, using the cacti operad.

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know whether it is expected (proven or not) that $CC^*(A)$ has any _more_ structure?

Comment: I would believe not.

Comment: Sorry for cutting in long after the conversation, but it seems that Kaufmann assumes A has inner product, and then works with usual Hochschild cochains. What if A is just associative and one works with cyclic cochains?